# Windows 8 key embedded in bios and now unable to retreive

Tags: windows-8, bios, dell-inspiron, product-id

I accidentally deleted the recovery partition in my dell inspiron 15r, and now i am unable to install windows 8. It says product ID not matching. I don't have the product id which is embedded in the bios. I have the new instalation disk's product id. How do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Get a MSDN/Technet ISO or delete the `ei.cfg` from your ISO. If this doesn't work, install the 90day trial of Win8 and run the tool R&W Everything and go to ACPI-->MSDM table. you'll find the key here:

[image]

Print out the key, format the 90day trial and use the key during setup.

Comment: how do i get the 90 day trial? any link?

Comment: here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx

Comment: this msdn page has been desolated by microsoft :( It was probably awkward information to microsoft or/and manufacturers.